# About stable manifold of a point

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, hyperbolic-dynamics

Let $(X, d)$ be a compact  metric space and $f:X\rightarrow X$ be a homeomorphism and

$$W^{s}(x)=\{y| d(f^{n}(x), f^{n}(y))\rightarrow as \ n\rightarrow \infty\}.$$

Question: What condition on $(X, f)$ imply that $intW^{s}(x)\neq \emptyset$?

Comment: What would distinguish an answer from simply restating the condition in your question?   I suppose I don't see a non-trivial aspect to your question.

Comment: I study dynamics of chain recurrent homeomorphisms on continua spaces ( a compact connected metric space). I need an example of chain recurrence homeomorphism with $intW^{s}(x)\neq \emptyset$ and conditions that imply  $intW^{s}(x)\neq \emptyset$?